# Angular Universal working on local host but not on Nginx Server

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx, universal

I have created a project using angular-universal.
after building the project it created browser, server, server.js and prerender.js. I want to know how it can run on the nginx.
with the current scenario i create the build of the project send it's zip file to the /var/www/html and unzip it there and it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your angular ssr project is running on same port , which you domain is listning to in nginx configuration file.
By default it listnes to 80 port , you need to change that port number in nginx configuration file and restart the server.